# Batch: "dont run if win7 or older"

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm looking for a batch-file sending me in the right path dependent upon the windows version This earlier code i used, have to ways. "if older than win7 jump toend" This does not work with windows 10.I'm having trouble understanding this calculation and i think there has to be a easy way to write this.

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ('ver') DO (
SET ver=%%a
)
SET v1=%ver:~27,1%
SET v2=%ver:~29,1%
IF %v1% LSS 6 GOTO JUMPTO
IF %v2% LSS 2 GOTO JUMPTO
call %~d0\bat\Timecounter\startwindowsupdate.bat
start %~d0\portup\portup.exe /u
GOTO:end
:JUMPTO
ECHO Windows version too old! Run windows update manualy! 
PAUSE
:end
Exit
```

Output of ver:`Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240]`

Tried something (more understandable for me)

```
@Echo OFF
Title Portup

ver | find "5.1" >nul && goto toold
ver | find "6.0" >nul && goto toold
ver | find "6.1" >nul && goto toold
ver | find "6.2" >nul && goto goodtogo
ver | find "6.3" >nul && goto goodtogo
ver | find "10.0" >nul && goto goodtogo

:toold
ECHO Windows to old. We don't support this OS
pause >nul
call %~d0\bat\avslutt.bat

:goodtogo
call %~d0\portup\portup.exe /u
```

Comment: Why `SET v2=%ver:~210,1%`?

Comment: Please, post the output of `ver` command in Win 10. Edit your question; do NOT post additional info in comments!

Comment: @dark fang I have tryed edited the code. its corrected to orginal.

Comment: Since `%ver:~29,1%` is "0" in Windows 10, you will get "Windows version too old! Run windows update manualy!" message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off

for /F "tokens=4,5 delims=. " %%a in ('ver') do set "version=%%a%%b"
if %version% leq 61 goto tooOld
```

[edit]: simplified code...

Comment: How and where do i learn this!? This is cryptically for me :)

Comment: @StianStørstfeskarAndersen: yes, `for` is not very intuitive. But it is one of the most powerful commands with batch. A start would be `for /?`. And/or keep reading here and soon you will understand most of it. (that's the way I learned it)

Answer (score 0):

Next code snippet based on `wmic os get /value` command output could help:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL enableextensions
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=. " %%G in ('
  wmic os get Version^, WindowsDirectory ^| findstr "\."
  ') do (
    set /A "_ver1=%%G" 
    set /A "_ver2=%%H" 
    set /A "_ver3=%%I" 
)
set _ver
```

Output on *Windows 8*:

```
==>ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]

==>D:\bat\SO\31855974.bat
_ver1=6
_ver2=3
_ver3=9600

==>
```